# How to add list [index] value to another list using method reference..?

Tags: java, java-8

This is my `list value [a,b,c,d]` ,  I tried to add `list[1] index value b`  to another list.. If am using lambda! am able to achieve this, any methods or ways was there to achieve same thing using method reference?. 
Below code i tried

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
//list1 values are like [a,b,c,d]
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.forEach(x-> {
    list2.add(x.get(1));
});
```

How to achieve same thing using `::`

```
list1.foreach(list1::add);
```

Comment: Is the value 1 in the `x.get(1)` always going to be the same? Because if it is a variable, you'll need to use a `Function<T, R>` as in take an argument return value, but if it is a constant, you can use a `Supplier<T>` as in return value.

Comment: @SamOrozco no... While data flowing the value is different but i need to take 1st index value

Comment: Are you trying to add the `1` or `"b"` to `list2`?

Comment: @Guy am trying to add 1st index value(b) in my list1 to list2

Comment: So are you looking for this? `list1.forEach(list2::add);`

Comment: @SamOrozco sorry I didn't get it, I want to add list1 1st index value to index2

Comment: @SamOrozco yes but here how can i add 1st index value

Comment: The thing I don't under stand is String.get() is not an actual method. So  do you just want the first character in the string.

Comment: @SamOrozco ok.. forget abt datatypes my list have a multiple values based on index position I want to add that value to another list using `::`

Answer (score 1):

`list1.forEach( x -> { } )` works like this: the operation between `{}` is done for every `x` from your list. This means that x is already an element and the `x.get(1)` will not provide the expected result.

One solution could be to simply use : `list2.add(list1.get(1));`

If you really want to use method reference and lambdas, you can use a `BiConsumer` *functional interface*. Here is an example:

```
    BiConsumer<List<String>, String> addConsumer = List::add;
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); //values [a,b,c,d]
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    addConsumer.accept(list2, list1.get(1));
```

Comment: It was working as i expected.. I need to achieve same thing using method reference` ::`

Comment: @itispa1 I've modified my answer.

Comment: Hey good one, but I need to avoid the bunch of lines..!!

Comment: There are only 2 lines for the actual operation. The other 2 are the lists.

Answer (score 1):

So if you think about the actual lambda, it is a `Consumer<T>` meaning that is can be reference by any method that takes a type of T and returns void. So in this example since you are looking for an something that uses a method reference I gave this. It isn't pretty but I want you to understand the point that `List<T>.forEach((T t) -> {})` is just `List<T>.forEach(Consumer<T>) || List<T>.forEach(<some method reference that takes type T as a single argument and returns void>)`

Here is a simple example.

```
package org.stackoverflow.thread_safe_account;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {


    private static List<String> knownList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //list1 values are like [a,b,c,d]
        List<String> createdList = new ArrayList<>();
        createdList.add("this");
        createdList.add("is");
        createdList.add("zoo");
        createdList.add("stackoverflow");

        createdList.forEach(Main::itemConsumer);


        if (!knownList.get(0).equals("t")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        }

        if (!knownList.get(1).equals("i")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        }

        if (!knownList.get(2).equals("z")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        }

        if (!knownList.get(3).equals("s")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        }
    }


    public static void itemConsumer(String item) {
        if (item.length() < 1) knownList.add("");
        else knownList.add(item.substring(0, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"...and returns void..."* — Well, the method doesn't *have* to return void. If the method returns anything, it is simply discarded.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` will return the index of the first occurrence of the object

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(list1.indexOf("b"));
```

Comment: Oh...!! I need to achieve this using method reference something like this `list1.forEach(list2::add)`

Comment: @itispa1 can you explain why?

Comment: @Guy I was about to ask the same thing.